# Get keys into JSON column in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, key, nvarchar

I have this Json in a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in SQL Server 2017:

```
{
    "coreTimes": {
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ANESTHESIOLOGY_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": 1
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ANESTHESIOLOGY_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": 2
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_SURGICAL_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": 3
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ROOM_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": 4
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ROOM_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_BLOCK_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_BLOCK_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_SURGICAL_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        }
    }
}
```

I need this result:

```
Column
{"value":1}
{"value":2}
{"value":3}
{"value":4}
{"value":null}
{"value":null}
{"value":null}
```

What SQL Server 2017 function can I use to get this result if json properties can change dynamically (the key 'coreTimes' is fixed)?

In Oracle I have used:

```
 SELECT res.*
 FROM sopinterventionsaux   ,
      JSON_TABLE ( operating_times, '$.coreTimes.*'
           COLUMNS (
              value VARCHAR2 ( 2000 ) FORMAT JSON PATH '$'
                    )
                ) res
```

In PostgreSQL:

```
select value from table, jsonb_each(column-> 'coreTimes')
```

And in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with default schema to parse the input `JSON`. In this case `OPENJSON()` returns a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`:

Table:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "coreTimes": {
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ANESTHESIOLOGY_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": 1
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ANESTHESIOLOGY_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": 2
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_SURGICAL_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": 3
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ROOM_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": 4
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ROOM_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_BLOCK_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_BLOCK_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_SURGICAL_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        }
    }
}'

CREATE TABLE Data (JsonData nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO Data (JsonData) VALUES (@json)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j.[value]
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonData, '$.coreTimes') j
```

Result:

```
---------------
value
---------------
{"value": 1}
{"value": 2}
{"value": 3}
{"value": 4}
{"value": null}
{"value": null}
{"value": null}
{"value": null}
```

If you want to get the exact values for the `value` keys, you need to use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (with columns definitions) and additional `APPLY` operator.

Statement:

```
SELECT j2.[value]
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonData, '$.coreTimes') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH ([value] int '$.value') j2
```

Result:

```
-----
value
-----
1
2
3
4
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following:

```
declare @j nvarchar(max) = '{
    "coreTimes": {
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ANESTHESIOLOGY_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": 1
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ANESTHESIOLOGY_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": 2
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_SURGICAL_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": 3
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ROOM_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": 4
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_ROOM_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_BLOCK_OUT_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_BLOCK_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        },
        "TMP_CLINICAL_TIMES_SURGICAL_IN_DATETIME": {
            "value": null
        }
    }
}'

select L1.[Value] from OPENJSON (@j, '$.coreTimes') AS L1
```